# Reading data from publisher (Kafka/RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka

I am researching a bit on how to use kafka for our needs and wanted to know if a consumer can query directly for data from producer.
From what I understand with kafka one can just produce from one end and consume from another end but there is no way for the consumers to interactively communicate with producers. It has to be a different tech stack ? Like storing in Redis ?

Does RabbitMQ provide this functionality if I can customize the exchange ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I need to first point out that there is a difference between "querying directly from a producer" and "communicating interactively with producers."

First, let's define producer as *"one who produces messages."* Similarly, we can define a consumer as *"one who receives and processes messages."*

Then, adopting that definition, you realize that, in any practical, real-world messaging system, everything connected to the messaging system is, at some point, both a producer and a consumer.

Typically, you set up specific services to accept messages from a queue, then produce some result message and publish it back to the broker, where it is routed to an appropriate queue for consumption by another (often the originally-producing) service.  Such a setup is known as **request-response**.

**Bottom Line**

1. It is not possible to query for messages directly from a producer under RabbitMQ. Producers put messages on an exchange, where they are routed to one or more queues. Consumers receive messages from a queue without any *a priori* insight into who exactly produces each message.
2. It is possible to communicate back to the producer of a specific message. To do so, the original producer sets up a reply queue, which is typically a randomly-named queue which auto-deletes once the original producer receives the reply and disconnects. This is one of many setups. Have a look at [this example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html) for details on how this might work.